# How to compare 2 files and extract the particular sequence using ID in first file and print the out put

Tags: grep, perl

File 1 (contain only selected IDs):

```
AAX50250
AAX50251
AAX50252
AAX50253
AAX50254
AAX50257
AAX50258
```

File 2 (Contains sequences with the IDs). This is a FASTA file where lines beginning with as `>` are the sequence ID and the subsequent lines are the sequence itself.

```
> AAX50250.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1:1770:1 gene:CTA_0001.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein
ATGAGCATCAGGGGAGTAGGAGGCAACGGGAATAGTCGAATCCCTTCTCATAATGGGGAT
GGATCGAATCGCAGAAGTCAAAATACGAAGAATAAAGTTGAAGATCGAGTTCGTTCTCTA
TATTCATCTCGTAGTAACGAAAATAGAGAATCTCCTTATGCAGTAGTAGACGTCAGCTCT
> AAX50251.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1915:2187:-1 gene:CTA_0002.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical membrane associated protein
ATGCTTTGTAAAGTTTGTAGAGGATTATCTTCTCTTATTGTTGTTCTCGGAGCTATAAAC
ACTGGAATTTTAGGAGTAACAGGGTATAAGGTAAACCTACTTACTCACCTGCTTGGTGAA
GGAACCATGTGGACACAAGCAGCTTATGTAGTAACGGGAATCGCTGGGGTTATGGTCTGC
> AAX50252.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:2388:2690:1 gene:CTA_0003.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:gatC description:glutamyl-tRNA(Gln) amidotransferase subunit C
ATGACAGAGTCATATGTAAACAAAGAAGAAATCATCTCTTTAGCAAAGAATGCTGCATTG
GAGTTGGAAGATGCCCACGTGGAAGAGTTCGTAACATCTATGAATGACGTCATTGCTTTA
ATGCAGGAAGTAATCGCGATAGATATTTCGGATATCATTCTTGAAGCTACAGTGCATCAT
TTCGTTGGTCCAGAGGATCTTAGAGAAGACATGGTGACTTCGGATTTTACTCAAGAAGAA
TAG
> AAX50262.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:13318:13932:-1 gene:CTA_0013.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:ybbP description:hypothetical membrane spanning protein
ATGTTCGTAGGTATAACGTATTACACCACACCTCTGTTGGAGATAGCTTTAATTTGGGTG
GTCCTTAATTATTTGCTAAAGTTTTTCTGGGGAACAGGCGCCATGGACCTCGTCTTTGGC
TTGTTGTCTTTTCTTTGCCTATTTGTTCTAGCAGAAAAACTTCATCTCCCCGTTATTCGC
AATTTGATGCTTCATGTAGTGAATATTGCGGCTATCGTGGTATTTATTATCTTCCAACCA
GAAATTCGCCTTGCTCTCTCTAGGATACGCTTGTGTAGAGAGAAATTTGTCATCAATATG
```

So now I have to compare File 1 which contains the selected ids with  File2 which has n number of sequences. We need to output the sequences associated with the IDs in file 1.

For example, the ID `AAX50250` which is in file 1 should return:

```
>AAX50250.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1:1770:1 gene:CTA_0001.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein
ATGAGCATCAGGGGAGTAGGAGGCAACGGGAATAGTCGAATCCCTTCTCATAATGGGGAT
GGATCGAATCGCAGAAGTCAAAATACGAAGAATAAAGTTGAAGATCGAGTTCGTTCTCTA
TATTCATCTCGTAGTAACGAAAATAGAGAATCTCCTTATGCAGTAGTAGACGTCAGCTCT
ATGATCGAGAGCACCCCAACGAGTGGAGAGACGACAAGAGCTTCGCGTGGAGTATTCAGT
CGTTTCCAAAGAGGTTTAGGACGAGTAGCTGACAAAGTAAGACGAGCTGTTCAGCGTGCG
TGGAGTTCAGTCTCTATAAGAAGATCGTCTGCAACAAGAGCCGCAGAATCCAGATCAAGT
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does each id starts with new line?

Comment: @snoop yes, lines starting with `>` are ID lines. See updated question. Nitha, in the future, please use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format your posts. Also, don't assume people know what FASTA is, you need to explain what the input file is. This isn't a site for bioinformaticians, only for Linux geeks, so don't expect us to know the specifics of this sort of thing :).

Comment: `AAX50250.1 cds:a ..........TATTCATCTCGTAGTAACGAAAATAGAGAATCTCCTTATGCAGTAGTAGACGTCAGCTCT` is this complete 1 sentence?

Comment: @snoop that's a complete entry, yes.  The line starting with a `>` is the ID line, and the rest (until the next `>`, or the end of the file) is the sequence.

Comment: DNA processing with unix text tools, amazing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a script to do this directly, but I suggest you use the two little scripts below instead. I have spent many years working with this sort of data and they have been very, very useful. If you're planning to do a lot of FASTA file manipulation, I suggest you use them.

1. `FastaToTbl`:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/awk -f
   {
           if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
           if (NR>1)
                       printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
           else 
               printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
           else 
                   printf "%s", $0
   }END{printf "\n"}
   ```
2. `TblToFasta`:

   ```
   #! /usr/bin/awk -f
   {
     sequence=$NF

     ls = length(sequence)
     is = 1
     fld  = 1
     while (fld < NF)
     {
        if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
        printf "%s " , $fld

        if (fld == NF-1)
         {
           printf "\n"
         }
         fld = fld+1
     }
     while (is <= ls)
     {
       printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
       is=is+60
     }
   }
   ```

Save the scripts above in your `$HOME/bin` directory (if it doesn't exist, create it then log out and log back in to add it to your `$PATH`). Then make the scripts executable with `chmod a+x ~/bin/TblToFasta ~/bin/FastaToTbl`.

The `FastaToTbl` will convert FASTA sequence files to tbl format (the sequence ID, followed by a tab character and the sequence, all in one line). Once they're in tbl format and you have the ID and the sequence on the same line, you can use `grep` to search for your IDs. Then, you pass the output through `TblToFasta` toi convert back to FASTA:

```
$ FastaToTbl file2 | grep -wFf file1 | TblToFasta
>AAX50250.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1:1770:1 gene:CTA_0001.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein 
ATGAGCATCAGGGGAGTAGGAGGCAACGGGAATAGTCGAATCCCTTCTCATAATGGGGAT
GGATCGAATCGCAGAAGTCAAAATACGAAGAATAAAGTTGAAGATCGAGTTCGTTCTCTA
TATTCATCTCGTAGTAACGAAAATAGAGAATCTCCTTATGCAGTAGTAGACGTCAGCTCT
>AAX50251.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1915:2187:-1 gene:CTA_0002.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical membrane associated protein 
ATGCTTTGTAAAGTTTGTAGAGGATTATCTTCTCTTATTGTTGTTCTCGGAGCTATAAAC
ACTGGAATTTTAGGAGTAACAGGGTATAAGGTAAACCTACTTACTCACCTGCTTGGTGAA
GGAACCATGTGGACACAAGCAGCTTATGTAGTAACGGGAATCGCTGGGGTTATGGTCTGC
>AAX50252.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:2388:2690:1 gene:CTA_0003.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:gatC description:glutamyl-tRNA(Gln) amidotransferase subunit C 
ATGACAGAGTCATATGTAAACAAAGAAGAAATCATCTCTTTAGCAAAGAATGCTGCATTG
GAGTTGGAAGATGCCCACGTGGAAGAGTTCGTAACATCTATGAATGACGTCATTGCTTTA
ATGCAGGAAGTAATCGCGATAGATATTTCGGATATCATTCTTGAAGCTACAGTGCATCAT
TTCGTTGGTCCAGAGGATCTTAGAGAAGACATGGTGACTTCGGATTTTACTCAAGAAGAA
TAG
```

The `grep` options used are:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings  (instead  of  regular
          expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.

   -f FILE, --file=FILE
          Obtain  patterns  from  FILE, one per line.  If this option is used
          multiple times or is combined with the -e (--regexp) option, search
          for all patterns given.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and
          therefore matches nothing.
   -w, --word-regexp
          Select only those lines containing matches that form  whole  words.
          The  test  is  that  the  matching  substring must either be at the
          beginning of the  line,  or  preceded  by  a  non-word  constituent
          character.   Similarly, it must be either at the end of the line or
          followed by a  non-word  constituent  character.   Word-constituent
          characters are letters, digits, and the underscore.
```

So, the `-f` lets us give it a file to read the search [patterns from, the `-F` tells it to treat the patters as strings and not regular expressions (otherwise, if your IDs contain `.` which they often do, that will be taken as "match any character") and the `-w` ensures we only match the entire ID, so that `foo` will not match `foobar`.

---

Alternatively, here's a quick and dirty perl one liner to do what you want:

```
perl -e 'open(F,"File1.txt");while(<F>){/(\S+)/; $k{$1}++}; while(<>){if(/>\s*(\S+?)(\.| )/){if($k{$1}){$k=1}else{$k=0}; } print if $k==1;}' File2.fa
```

Or, slightly less dirty:

```
perl -e 'open(F,"File1.txt");
         while(<F>){
            /(\S+)/; 
            $k{$1}++
         } 
         while(<>){
            if(/>\s*(\S+?)(\.| )/){
                if($k{$1}){$k=1}
                else{$k=0}
            } 
            print if $k==1
        }' File2.fa
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
$ awk -F'[ .]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}/^>/{p=$2 in a}p' file1 file2
> AAX50250.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1:1770:1 gene:CTA_0001.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical protein
ATGAGCATCAGGGGAGTAGGAGGCAACGGGAATAGTCGAATCCCTTCTCATAATGGGGAT
GGATCGAATCGCAGAAGTCAAAATACGAAGAATAAAGTTGAAGATCGAGTTCGTTCTCTA
TATTCATCTCGTAGTAACGAAAATAGAGAATCTCCTTATGCAGTAGTAGACGTCAGCTCT
> AAX50251.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:1915:2187:-1 gene:CTA_0002.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding description:hypothetical membrane associated protein
ATGCTTTGTAAAGTTTGTAGAGGATTATCTTCTCTTATTGTTGTTCTCGGAGCTATAAAC
ACTGGAATTTTAGGAGTAACAGGGTATAAGGTAAACCTACTTACTCACCTGCTTGGTGAA
GGAACCATGTGGACACAAGCAGCTTATGTAGTAACGGGAATCGCTGGGGTTATGGTCTGC
> AAX50252.1 cds:annotated chromosome:ASM1212v1:Chromosome:2388:2690:1 gene:CTA_0003.1 gene_biotype:protein_coding transcript_biotype:protein_coding gene_symbol:gatC description:glutamyl-tRNA(Gln) amidotransferase subunit C
ATGACAGAGTCATATGTAAACAAAGAAGAAATCATCTCTTTAGCAAAGAATGCTGCATTG
GAGTTGGAAGATGCCCACGTGGAAGAGTTCGTAACATCTATGAATGACGTCATTGCTTTA
ATGCAGGAAGTAATCGCGATAGATATTTCGGATATCATTCTTGAAGCTACAGTGCATCAT
TTCGTTGGTCCAGAGGATCTTAGAGAAGACATGGTGACTTCGGATTTTACTCAAGAAGAA
TAG
```

The script above can be expanded to:

```
awk -F'[ .]' '       # set the field separator to space or dot
        NR == FNR {  # for the lines of the first file
            a[$0]    # Store the line in an array
            next     # And skip to the next record
        }
        /^>/{        # For lines of the second file starting with `>`
            p = $2 in a # Set flag to true if index is present in array
        }
        p            # print line if flag is set
      ' file1 file2
```

Comment: @terdon and @ user000001 so whether this one line command solves my problem `awk -F'[ .]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}/^>/{p=$2 in a}p' file1 file2` I tried it but I couldn't get any clear out put

Comment: @Nitha yes, this *should* work on your example files but it might fail if your input isn't exactly as you show. For example, it will fail if you include the accession version (the `.N`) in your list of IDs.

Comment: @terdon, I have tried this command but unfortunately I am not getting the output.

" awk -F'[ .]' 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next}/^>/{p=$2 in a}p' CAI_Filtered_ID-A.txt (file1) CHT_A.fa (file2) >test.txt "

but in output file test.txt I am not getting any out put.

could you plz tell me where I am doing mistake.

I have given files as i shown in example.

File 1- list of IDs and File 2- consit of fasta sequences

Comment: @Nitha we can't discuss this in the comments. Either edit your question and add this information, or ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: @Nitha 1) please stop asking questions in comments! Ask a new question about this. 2) Of course there's no `grep` command for that. `grep` is a tool tat searches for patterns, it can't do any of the things you ask for. 3) what you need is a script. Start with my `FastaToTbl` command: `FastaToTbl file.fa | awk _F"\t" '{print length($2)}'` and try to write one yourself. Then, ask a question either here or on [unix.se] about any specific problem you have.